# Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'EnumeratedSequence<Set<…>>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I want to use a ForEach loop to iterate over a property of a Set entry from a CoreData collection:

```
ForEach(entry.receivers, id: \.id){ receiver in
    Text("\(receiver.name)")
}
```

entry is an object from CoreData with a property receivers that's a Set of objects with a property name.

But this leads to the following error:

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'EnumeratedSequence<Set<GroupMember>>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `entry.receivers`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: entry is an object from CoreData with a property receivers that's a Set of objects with a property name.

Comment: Does `Array(entry.receivers)` work?

Comment: I implemented an extension for my CoreData Collection with Comparable and used entry.receivers.sorted(by: <)